# When retrieving an entity with a ManyToMany relationship, the data is not being displayed

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working on a Java application using Spring Boot, where I have an entity Messages, which has a Many-to-Many relationship with Groups. The application is intended to manage notifications and group associations for messages. However, I'm facing an issue: when I retrieve Messages using messageService.findAll(), the array of groups associated with each message is unexpectedly empty.

Here's the output I get: Message(id=2, text=ds, deadline=null, isRelevant=false, sendingDate=2023-12-28T06:36:02.910126, numOfNotif=1, groups=[]).

I've included the relevant models and service implementations below for reference.

**Message**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "Messages", indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "is_relevant", name = "is_relevant_idx")
})
public class    Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "message_text", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "deadline")
    private LocalDateTime deadline;

    @Column(name = "is_relevant")
    private Boolean isRelevant = true;

    @Column(name = "sending_date")
    private LocalDateTime sendingDate = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Column(name = "num_of_notif")
    private Integer numOfNotif = 1;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "Notifications_Groups",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "notif_id" ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"))
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, Set<Group> groups, Boolean isRelevant) {
        this.text = text;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.isRelevant = isRelevant;
    }

    public Message(String text, LocalDateTime deadline, Set<Group> groups) {
        this.text = text;
        this.deadline = deadline;
        this.groups = groups;
    }
}
```

**Group**

```
@Data
@Table(name = "Student_Groups", indexes = {
        @Index(columnList = "chat_id", name = "chat_id_idx")
})
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "chat_id")
    private Long chatId;

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    private String groupName;

    @Column(name = "is_banned")
    private boolean isBanned = false;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
    private Set<Message> messages = new HashSet<>();


    public Group() {
    }

    public boolean getBanned() {
        return isBanned;
    }

}
```

**MessageRepo**

```
public interface MessageRepo extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {

}
```

**MessageService**

```
    public List<Message> findAll();
    public void save(Message message);
}
```

**MessageServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Message> findAll() {
        return messageRepo.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id"));
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Message message) {
        messageRepo.save(message);
    }

}
```

To address this issue, I first tried changing the fetch type to EAGER for the Groups collection in my Message entity. However, this didn't resolve the problem.

Next, I attempted a different approach by using a custom JPQL query with an eager fetching strategy. I modified the method in my repository to use a @Query annotation with SELECT m FROM Message m JOIN FETCH m.groups. This was supposed to eagerly load the associated Group entities when retrieving Message entities. Despite these efforts, the problem persists.

I've double-checked the database entries and ensured that the relationships are correctly established. The JPQL query seems correct, but I'm puzzled as to why the groups are still not being fetched. Could this be related to transactional boundaries, or is there something else I'm missing in my configuration or understanding of JPA's fetching strategies?

Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or what else I can try would be greatly appreciated.